# creating networkx in python

Tags: python, networkx

How can I draw such graph by deciding the number of nodes
and the connection between the core and the others nodes? 
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgnXk.png]

```
G=nx.star_graph(20)
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
colors=range(20)
nx.draw(G,pos,node_color='#A0CBE2',edge_color=colors,width=4,edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues,with_labels=False)
plt.savefig("edge_colormap.png") # save as png
plt.show() # display
```

I don't care about the colors, I want the shape.

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation what the function arguments are and what structure you're supposed to pass to them?

Comment: I want to fixing the nodes and drawing edges when core node have a relation with other nodes

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. By the way, you can see the nodes and edges (connecting lines between nodes) you have with `G.nodes()` and `G.edges()`. There are also methods to add new nodes and edges. Knowing all that, can you proceed with your problem?